# Applescript & Rules in Mail

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to execute the following Applescript within a Rule I set up in Mac Mail.  I'm running OS 10.10.1 Yosemite on my iMac.  My Rule looks for a particular email I receive every day, then instructs Mail to execute my Applescript.  The Rule works perfectly when I manually highlight the email and click on "Apply Rules"; however, when I start up my computer in the morning and receive my first mail of the day.  The Applescript program gets caught in never ending loop, which is evidenced by the whirling icon that appears in the menu bar.  BTW:  My automator routine works perfectly.  My thinking is that the Applescript gets confused trying to execute while Mail is downloading all my mail????  Any suggestions??  Oh, I'm a novice...Thx

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        -- Select the Print menu item
        click (first menu item of menu "File" of menu bar 1 whose name begins with "Print")
        tell window 1
            -- Wait until the print sheet appears
            repeat until sheet 1 exists
            end repeat
            tell sheet 1
                -- Click the PDF button
                click menu button "PDF"
                -- Select the PDF to SBS Dropbox menu item
                click (first menu item of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" whose name begins with "PDF to SBS Dropbox")
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use the Applescript handler called by mail rules:

```
on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
```

Inside this handler you have access to the mails that matched your mail rule conditions and do whatever you like. Here is the skeleton you can use to add your code:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
                -- place your code here
            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

In your special case I think we can try to put your code inside the repeat-loop and let mail open the mail before execution and close it after printing:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        tell application "Mail"

            -- walk through all matching messages
            repeat with thisMessage in theMessages
                -- open the message
                set openedMail to open thisMessage

                -- perform your UI scripting
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "Mail"
                        -- Select the Print menu item
                        click (first menu item of menu "File" of menu bar 1 whose name begins with "Print")
                        tell window 1
                            -- Wait until the print sheet appears
                            repeat 30 times
                                if sheet 1 exists then exit repeat
                                delay 0.5
                            end repeat
                            tell sheet 1
                                -- Click the PDF button
                                click menu button "PDF"
                                -- Select the PDF to SBS Dropbox menu item
                                click (first menu item of menu 1 of menu button "PDF" whose name begins with "PDF to SBS Dropbox")
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell

                -- close the message
                close openedMail

            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

It's not tested yet! And I prevent the script from running in an infinite loop when trying to access the print sheet now.

Give it a try! Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thank you.  Your first suggestion resulted in another continuous loop; where Mail opened the email, but didn't complete the task.  Which it then canceled and tried again and again.  The 2nd suggestion appears to work perfectly; however, it doesn't Close the email after completion of the task.  Not that that's an issue, but I thought you'd like to know.  I'll see how it works tomorrow morning when I receive Friday's new email.  Thanks again...